# Get the number of characters

Tags: java, split

I need to get the count of each repeated characters separately....I have tried..but it returns only the count of unique count of characters...

Input :

```
SSDDVVDSSS
```

output :

```
S - 5
D - 3
V - 2
```

here is my code

```
public class q2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println(countUniqueCharacters("SSDDVVDSSS"));
}


public static int countUniqueCharacters(String input) {
boolean[] isItThere = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE];
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    isItThere[input.charAt(i)] = true;
}

int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < isItThere.length; i++) {
    if (isItThere[i] == true){
        count++;
    }
}

return count;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are the issues in your code:

1. you are defining array with 65535 size which is unnecessary for 26 characters.
2. You defined boolean array within which each element would store two values either true or false which is very much needed if you need to see if character exists in your String but doesn't suits your algorithm.
3. You have shared counter variable which is going to give you length of String i.e. how many characters you have in your string and is not what you need.

There are multiple ways in which you could solve this problem:

- Using int array with index from 0 - 26 that maintains count of character A-Z and finally you print the count:

  ```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      int[] counts = countUniqueCharacters("SSDDVVDSSS");
      for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
          if (counts[i] != 0) {
              System.out.println("char " + ((char) ('A' + i)) + " repeated " + counts[i] + " times");
          }
      }
  }

      public static int[] countUniqueCharacters(String input) {
      int[] counts = new int[26];
      for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
          counts[input.charAt(i) - 'A']++;
      }
      return counts;
  }
  ```
- Another way is to use map with character as key and int as value which would represent the count of that character repeatation.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "SSDDVVDSSS";
        int counts[] = new int[(int) Character.MAX_VALUE];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            counts[(int) c]++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            if (counts[i] > 0)
                System.out.print((char) i + "-" + counts[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: i need to get the minimum repeated number of character that repeated.but it returns 0.how can i do this??

Comment: @ChaturaMohotti Above solution give output like D-3
S-5
V-2 . What are your exact requirement please explain.

Comment: i need to select the 2 as the out put here. Because the minimum repeated number is 2.can you tell me how can i do it??

Comment: @ChaturaMohotti Now you can write program for get minimum value inside array named counts.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "SSDDVVDSSS";
        int counts[] = new int[(int) Character.MAX_VALUE];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            counts[(int) c]++;
        }
        

        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            if (counts[i] > 0)
                System.out.println(counts[i]);
        }
        
        int min=counts[0];
        for(int j=1;j<counts.length;j++){
        if(min<counts[j]){
        counts[j]=min;
        }
            System.out.println(min);
        }
    }

Comment: but im getting 0 as the answer

Comment: @ChaturaMohotti for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
   if (counts[i] > 0) {
    System.out.print((char) i + "-" + counts[i] + "\n");
    arr[index] = counts[i];
    index++;
   }
  }
  
  int min = arr[0];
  for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
   if (arr[i] > 0) {
    if (arr[i] < min) {
     min = arr[i];
    }
   }
  }
  
  System.out.println(min); where int[] arr = new int[counts.length];
  int index  = 0;

Comment: @ChaturaMohotti above is solution. Please see if anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your last 'for' loop goes over the counter array and count how much entries with true value it contains.
Therefore you get number of unique chars.

Try this:

```
public class q2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    countUniqueCharacters("SSDDVVDSSS");
}


public static void countUniqueCharacters(String input) {


    Map<Character,Integer>  map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){

        if (map.get(input.charAt(i)) == null){
             map.put(input.charAt(i),1);
        }
        else{
            map.put(input.charAt(i),map.get(input.charAt(i))+1);
        }
    }

     System.out.print(map);
}
```

}

Comment: can i put this to an array

Comment: yes you can. something like: int counts[] = new int[(int) Character.MAX_VALUE];